# Mount a folder as a removable drive on Windows

Tags: windows-server-2008, mount, usb

I'm using some compression software that requires a USB dongle to operate. There's nothing special about the dongle, it's just a usb drive with files on it. We're attempting to move the operation into AWS, so I'd like to be able to virtualize the drive since we can't really plug it in.

I've tried using `substr` to mount it, but the application is only looking for removable drives, and will not recognize the substr drive.

Is there a way to tell `substr` to mount it as removeable, or another way to do this? Maybe make an ISO and mount that, or would that appear as a CD drive? I have not been able to track down how to do this, it seems everyone wants to mount ISO's from USB drives, not as them.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/391679/is-there-software-to-fully-emulate-a-usb-hard-drive

Comment: Be aware that by emulating the USB dongle, you are probably in violation of your license agreement with the software vendor. I'd contact them and ask what their support (if any) method for running in the cloud is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I googled "usb drive emulation" and found this...
https://superuser.com/questions/391679/is-there-software-to-fully-emulate-a-usb-hard-drive

Have you checked that software out?

Comment: That totally worked, thank you! I also used Iso Recorder http://isorecorder.alexfeinman.com/isorecorder.htm to create the iso.